# MS Access SQL Select most recent date per ID and per Skill

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have this table where each candidate has multiple skills and each of their skills has multiple entry dates (to track their progress in improving each skill over time).

[image]

I have this sql statement:

```sql
select cs.*
from [Candidate Skills] as cs
where cs.CandidateID = 186298
    and cs.[Skill Date] = (select max(cs2.[Skill Date])
                           from [Candidate Skills] as cs2);
```

but that only pulls the line with 2/16/2024 as the Skill Date. I need it to pull the most recent row for each skill for candidate 186298.

[image]

How can I revise my sql statement?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

You check for every Candidate/Skill combination whether there are more recent rows and remove those. I.e. you only show rows for which no newer row exists, i.e. only the rows that are themselves the newest.

For example like this:

```sql
select cs.*
from [Candidate Skills] as cs
    left join [Candidate Skills] as X on X.[Skill Date] >= cs.[Skill Date]
                                     and X.CandidateID = cs.CandidateID
                                     and X.Skill = cs.Skill
where X.CandidateID is null
    and cs.CandidateID = 186298
```

Here `X` contains rows newer than the row in `cs`. So when `X` is present, we don’t want that row.

Perhaps you could also use `where not exists()`, not sure if this sql dialect supports that. (Indeed I’m not sure if it supports my `left join` there. You may have to put extra parentheses or something.)

Your attempt is on the right track. You could also do it that way, but you forgot to compare Candidate and Skill in the subquery.

Comment: scmings asked for "the most recent row for each skill". I think maybe you have the date compare for X backwards.

Comment: Hm, I don’t think so? But I’m too lazy to reason it out or stage testing data. But the idea is to find *more recent* rows to self-join and then only take rows for which none were found, i.e. there is nothing *more* recent, i.e. the row is the most recent, no?